# ehcache monitor: installation/configuration

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, ehcache, administration

In the documentation http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/monitor there is a phrase:

> It is recommended that you install the Monitor on an Operations server separate to production.

Why it is so? What will be if I install it on the production?

And, the second question on which I did not find the answer there - is it really this monitor does not affect the performance of application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain what I think they mean.

First of all, I don't think the intention is that you not use the Monitor in production. Rather, I think they mean that the Monitor should be installed on a separate server in a production environment. There are at least three good reasons to do this.

The first is one of security. The clients that your production server is servicing shouldn't be able to reach the Monitor's services. By putting it on a separate server (perhaps behind a firewall) you prevent this.

The second is one of landscape simplicity. The Monitor can monitor several servers. By putting it on a separate server, you prevent one application server from being "special" - all the application servers are identical as far as this is concerned. Easier for scaling and maintenance of your landscape.

The third reason is one of performance. Calls to the Monitor won't impact the application server/s. This is as it should be.

As for the second part of your question- obviously, adding ehcache monitoring will affect performance to some extent. Probably it's meant to only incur a minimal overhead, but nothing is completely without cost. But if you end up optimizing the caches, it will probably be worth it.

I found this paragraph detailing how often the Monitor samples:

> Memory is estimated by sampling. The first 15 puts or updates are measured and then every 100th put or update

(this is from the statistics section of [the Monitor page](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/monitor#statistics))